# Install rpm using sudo

Tags: sudo

Install rpm using sudo
I want to be able to have user install rpm as sudo rpm –hiv “ rmpname” and not have to put in password or log in as root. I am not sure where to update the sudo user file… thanks for any help ….

Centos 6.5

Usually I change to su and install rpm what I need is to create a cmd sudo –rpm to install rpm

Answer (score 0):

The `/etc/sudoers` file should be edited with a special `visudo` command rather than a normal text editor. Append this line after all of the corresponding user's rules:

```
<username> ALL = NOPASSWD: /path/to/the/rpm/command
```